# Class Extends In Php

Tags: php

I have 3 pieces of the file

```
1. a.php

    <?
    class a {
         public function name () {
             return "My name is ukungzulfah";
         }
    }
    ?>

2. b.php

    <?
    class b extends a {
         function na () {
             echo $ this-> name ();
         }
    }

    ?>

3.c.php

    <?
    include "a.php";
    include "b.php";

    $ te = new b;
    echo $ te:: na ();

    ?>
```

The result is an error:
Fatal error: Using $ this Pls note in object context in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ sampleNetbeans \ controller \ welcome.php on line 4.

Is there something wrong with the code above. if called from b.php was no problem, the problem only if the call by c.php file.

Comment: can you put the full code of all 3 classes

Answer (score 4):

You are using static syntax (`$object::method()`) when you need to use instance syntax (`$object->method()`).

Try `echo $te->na();` instead of `echo $te::na();`.

This is the only problem I can see in the code you have pasted, except for the unusual whitespace (`$ te` and `$ te:: na ()`) which actually causes compiler errors for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, somehow I forgot about it, perhaps because soon the feast so many minds, once again thank you.